# Troubles with resizing UserControl children or perhaps a better method than using an UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am currently developing a little WPF program that acts as a template and recorder of offline tickets.

The design of my program is currently based upon creating a user control as a ticket. This ticket (UserControl) is a group of Text Fields. Here is a screenshot of my usercontrol.

[Ticket (UserControl)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Z0I.png)

My program then reads each field in the ticket and stores it in a text file.

This all works expect for resizing. WPF is a pain to resize (in my opinion). I don't have much experience with WPF but I can't get the UserControl to resize on the grid I am using in my main window. The control resizes but none of the children of my user control resize.

Here is how my main window looks

[Main Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIJkH.png)

The ticket is added to the grid under the Ticket Tab. Everything here resizes expect the UserControl's children (Textfields, buttons, etc).

**Question:** Is there a better way to make something like this (IE not using a user control) or do I just need to use a messy grid, and a ton of stretch and auto properties on my UserControl and her Children to get this to work?

Perhaps I am just using UserControls completely wrong in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of most WPF controls (and therefore user controls) is to expand and occupy as much space as available

for example (xml namespaces elided for clarity)

```
<Window>
  <Button Content="Hello" />
</Window>
```

would create one big button if you maximized your window

In your case I am guessing you are using the Visual Studio designer to align and size the individual controls. One behavior with the designer generated code is to set `Margin` property if you move the controls around to position them and `Width` and `Height` if you adjust the size. This causes them to stop expanding or stretching.

Typically, I avoid using the visual designer but directly use the XAML editor to design the layout and verify that it appears as intended on the Visual designer.

While it is nice having controls expand and contract based on the screen availability, it might at times result is poor or odd layouts and sizes. Typically when I use a `Grid` as layout, I set the individual children's `MinWidth`, `MinHeight`, `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` for controls that don't look good when stretched or compressed too much (RadioButtons, CheckBox). For some controls it is desirable to stretch only horizontally (Single line text input say for the problem definition field in your case) where it would be prudent to set the `Grid` row height to `auto` so that the Control get just enough height that it requires.

It might also be OK to use a `GridSplitter` with sensible min/max width constraints to allow the user the resize the LHS column if his window size is too small

Something like this (not tested though)

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
      <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>              
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>  
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="350" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>

      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>

      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>

      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- first column -->

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Text="Employee ID" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Text="{Binding EmployeeID}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="2"
               Text="User Name" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="3"
             Text="{Binding UseName}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="4"
               Text="Computer Name" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="5"
              Text="{Binding ComputerName}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="6"
               Text="PhoneNumber" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="7"
              Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.Row="8"
               Text="Location" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="9"
             Grid.RowSpan="2"
             Text="{Binding Location}" />

    <Button Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="11"
            Text="Copy All" />

    <!-- second column -->

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Text="Problem Description" />

    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="1">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    

      <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
               Text="{Binding ProblemDescription}" />    

      <Button Grid.Column="1"
              Content="C" />
    </Grid>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="2"
               Text="Notes" />

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="3"
             Grid.RowSpan="7"
             Text="{Binding Notes}" />    

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="10"
               Text="Resolution" />

    <Grid Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="11">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    

      <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
               Text="{Binding Resolution}" />    

      <Button Grid.Column="1"
              Content="C" />
    </Grid>

    <!-- splitter to make the columns resizable -->

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.RowSpan="12"
                  Width="3"
                  Background="Blue" />    
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Yeah I will give this a shot. I was trying to avoid using a grid with columns and rows. However after reading what you put and doing some research it seems this may be the only way to do what I want.